# Get recently viewed products excluding particular product ID in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, recently-viewed

I need to get recently viewed products for a customer in a product view but excluding the current product the customer is viewing. I have,

```
class Index extends Action
{
    protected $recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $recentProducts = $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->getData();
    }
}
```

This **$recentProducts** returns particular number of recently viewed products based on the admin configuration. For example, if the limit of recent products is 5, this returns 5 products. But I need 5 products excluding current product.

How can I exclude a particular product by providing it's ID?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need this on product detail page?

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal Yes

Comment: you can do this using xml see my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add **excludeProductIds()** filter to collection like,

```
$recentProducts = $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->excludeProductIds($productId)->getData();
```

This will always return required number of products without including the given **productId**.

Answer (score 0):

Set limit to 6 if you want 5 products.

Sort collection by descending order

```
$recentProducts = $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->setOrder("index_id","DESC")->getData();
```

Remove first element of your array

```
$recentProducts = array_shift($recentProducts);
```

Now your final collection would skip your current product.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But providing limit 6 to get 5 products seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the layout file **catalog_product_view.xml** :

```
<block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
            <action method="setPageSize">
                <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
```

Comment: This looks good to display recent products during page onload. But controller seems to be better option to me, since I'm appending this content using AJAX. Thanks for your solution.